# HttpURLConnection.getInputStream very slow

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, androidhttpclient

HttpURLConnection.getInputStream takes very much time when compared to iPhone App which uses the same server side services.

The following code is used for the service :

```
         date= new java.util.Date();             
         Log.d("time","Time Stamp before posting  "+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

         URL ur= new URL(url);           
         HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
         conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
         conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);             
         OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                 new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
         writer.write(getQuery(nameValuePairs));
         writer.close();
         os.close();
         conn.connect();

         StringBuffer response=null;             
         try{           
             Log.d("time","Time Stamp bfr InputStream  "+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));    

             InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

             date= new java.util.Date();             
             Log.d("time","Time Stamp aftr InputStream  "+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));            

             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             String line;
             response = new StringBuffer(); 
             while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                 response.append(line);
                 response.append('\r');
             }
             rd.close();
             response.toString();
             result=response.toString();

         } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

To check where the service takes time, I put the log entries to print TimeStamp.

The average time for the process is as follows :

> Average time for posting to server takes less than 2 Mil seconds
>   Average time for creating input stream takes almost 5 seconds
>
> Average time for writing response is less than 2 mil seconds.

Any idea on why the input stream takes much time which makes the entire service very slow?

Answer (score 1):

You're not measuring what you think you're measuring. Nothing gets written to the server until you call getInputStream() or getResponseCode(). So you're really measuring:

- connection time
- transmission time
- processing time at the server

when you think you're just measuring getInputStream() time.

The reason is that HttpURLConnection auto-sets the content-length header, by buffering all the output. You can avoid that by using chunked transfer mode. Then at least you will see where the time is really going.

Comment: How would we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set urlConnection.setConnectTimeout() to a lower timeout.

The class documentation for URLConnection.setConnectTimeout() says:

> Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting. Connecting to a server will fail with a SocketTimeoutException if the timeout elapses before a connection is established. The default value of 0 causes us to do a blocking connect. This does not mean we will never time out, but it probably means you'll get a TCP timeout after several minutes.
>
> Warning: if the hostname resolves to multiple IP addresses, this
>   client will try each in RFC 3484 order. If connecting to each of these
>   addresses fails, multiple timeouts will elapse before the connect
>   attempt throws an exception. Host names that support both IPv6 and
>   IPv4 always have at least 2 IP addresses.

I originally had mine set to `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30000);` and then changed it to `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000)`. Immediately, I saw quicker results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean you saw quicker connection failures, when you got them at all. Hard to see how this solves the OP's problem.

Comment: It is strange but it works! Maybe the while loop is looping for ever or something else, but for me this answer worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a bug introduced in JDK 7. "HttpServer induces a 1000 ms delay when using the keep-alive cache". See:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8009548

Depending on your purposes, the suggested workaround is to multi-thread the HttpUrlConnection. For example, if you're using HttpServer you can do:

```
server.setExecutor( Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 ) );
```

Comment: Only if he's using `HttpServer` at the other end. No evidence of that. And the suggested workaround is to multi-thread the *server,* which again is irrelevant.